# Vertification check help in swiftui

Tags: swift, validation, button, swiftui

I am trying to only allow the user to select only one of the topics rather than at least one topic. I have written the code for this, however, it does not seem to do what I hope. I believe the issue could be with the line shown below, however, as a first time swift user I am unaware of what the exact issue could be.
allTopics.filter { $0 }.count == 0 && NumberSelected != nil}

(I have removed several sections of code from here for other text etc that will not be relevant to this question.)

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

//Creating Variables for Revision Topics
@State private var setMemory = false
@State private var setSocialInfluence = false
@State private var setApproaches = false
@State private var setPsychopathology = false
@State private var setBiopsychology = false
@State private var setAttachment = false
@State private var setIssuesandDebates = false
@State private var setSchizophrenia = false
@State private var setResearchMethods = false
@State private var oneClicked = false

//Creating Buttons for Number of Questions
        let buttons = ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]
@State public var NumberSelected: Int?


//Creating Variables for 'Continue' Button
let button = ["Continue"]
@State public var buttonContinue: Int?

//Making Sure User Selects Topic(s) and Number of Questions
private var allTopics: [Bool] {
   [setMemory, setSocialInfluence, setApproaches, setPsychopathology, setBiopsychology, setAttachment, setIssuesandDebates, setSchizophrenia, setResearchMethods]}

   private var TopicSelected: Bool {
   allTopics.contains { $0 }}

   private var isFormValid: Bool {
   allTopics.filter { $0 }.count == 0 && NumberSelected != nil}


var body: some View {
    

            Group{
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
            Toggle("Memory",isOn: $setMemory)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                .tint(Color(red: 0.902, green: 0.755, blue: 0.161))
            Toggle("Approaches",isOn: $setApproaches)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                .tint(Color(red: 0.945, green: 0.442, blue: 0.022))
            Toggle("Biopsychology",isOn: $setBiopsychology)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                .tint(Color(red: 0.817, green: 0.065, blue: 0.287))
                
            Toggle("Issues & Debates",isOn: $setIssuesandDebates)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                .tint(Color(red: 0.399, green: 0.06, blue: 0.947))
            Toggle("Research Methods Year 1 & 2",isOn: $setResearchMethods)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                    .tint(Color(red: 0.105, green: 0.561, blue: 0.896))}
                .padding(.leading, -135.0)
                .padding(.top, -10)
                
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
            Toggle("Social Influence",isOn: $setSocialInfluence)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                .tint(Color(red: 0.902, green: 0.755, blue: 0.17))
            Toggle("Psychopathology",isOn: $setPsychopathology)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                .tint(Color(red: 0.945, green: 0.442, blue: 0.022))
            Toggle("Attachment",isOn: $setAttachment)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                .tint(Color(red: 0.817, green: 0.065, blue: 0.287))
            Toggle("Schizophrenia",isOn: $setSchizophrenia)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
            .tint(Color(red: 0.394, green: 0.061, blue: 0.943))}
                .padding(.top, -192)
                .padding(.leading, 180)
    }
        
//Number of Questions - Selected Buttons
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
            ForEach(0..<buttons.count, id: \.self) {button in
                Button(action: {
                    self.NumberSelected = button
                    
                }) {
                    Text("\(self.buttons[button])")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Black-White"))
                        .font(.title3)
                        .padding()
                        .background(self.NumberSelected == button ? Color("Custom Gray"): Color("White-Black"))
                    .clipShape(Capsule())}}
            
            }
            
        }
    }
        
//Continue Button           
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
        ForEach(0..<button.count, id: \.self) {button in
                Button(action: {
                    self.buttonContinue = button
                    
                }) {
                    
//Links Continue Button To Next Page
                    NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                        Text("Continue")
                    }

//'Continue' Button is Disabled if User Has Not Selected Values
                    .clipShape(Capsule())}}.disabled(!isFormValid)  
        }
        
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using that as reference before I posted this question, however, I only started coding in swift about one month ago and so I was unsure of how the answer in the question link could be used in my code

Comment: I think you need a `Picker` instead of the toggles since you only want one selected.  What you are trying todo is not built in you would have to create it yourself.

Comment: I have seen many examples use pickers but I wasn't sure how to implement this? if you don't mind, would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: There is way to much extra code in your sample. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)  they might help you. SO is not a code writing service to get your code working it takes an entire rewrite to change all those bools to some kind of object.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the code in hope of removing any unnecessary details. How would I be able to change any one of those bools into an object?

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71750648/bool-to-nil-always-returns-true-issue-in-swiftui) where you have already accepted an answer?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Because the responses received from that didn't work for this. I tried using the same solution on the toggles and although I got no errors, the simulator still allowed me to select several topics

Comment: That was why I asked you if the given answer really worked in that question, which you said it did. So now you have changed your mind?

Comment: the answer worked for the code I had shown which was in a separate file to this. It meant the user was only able to select one of the options to the questions. However when I implemented that in different code - listed above, it did not work, as so I posted a new question

Comment: @User8149 with a `struct` so you can have custom variables such as the `name`, `isSelected` if you decide to allow multiple selection later, `color` so you can save the individual colors, etc. An `enum` yes not seem to be the correct option for this case. Because it seems like each topic will have many other variables that relate to it such as questions and answers. You need to look at your project as a whole that is growing and keep like things together.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to restructure your code. While your approach with `@State var` is working for a few choices it becomes very cumbersome to deal with as your code advances.

My solution has implications for your code other than just the exclusive selection of toggles. This issues you will have to address on your own, or ask a new question.

- Create an enum holding your choices

  ```
   enum SelectedOption: CaseIterable{
    case memory, approaches, biopsychology

    var prettyDescription: String{ // used for getting a description in the view
        switch self{
        case .memory:
            return "Memory"
        case .approaches:
            return "Approaches"
        case .biopsychology:
            return "Biopsychology"
        }
    }
   }
  ```

I´ve done only 3 but this can be expanded without to much effort.

- Delete the now deprected `@State var`s from your view and replace them with a single one:

  ```
  @State private var selectedOption: SelectedOption?
  ```
- Change the VStack containing your Toggles:

  ```
    VStack{
            ForEach(SelectedOption.allCases, id: \.self){ enumCase in
                Toggle(enumCase.prettyDescription, isOn: Binding(get: { selectedOption == enumCase }, set: { _,_ in selectedOption = enumCase }))
                                .toggleStyle(.button)
                                .tint(Color(red: 0.817, green: 0.065, blue: 0.287))
            }
        }
  ```

You are now itterating over all cases SelectedOption can contain and using a binding to determine whether the toggle should be selected or not depending on `selectedOption`

Comment: Instead of "prettyDescription", consider conforming to CustomStringConvertible protocol, so that e.g. print(mySelectedOption) does the right thing

Comment: @Shadowrun i don´t think this is neccessary here. And I tried to stay as simple as possible to prevent the user from further confusion.